# How to save XML node values to string parameters

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, httphandler

I have a custom HTTP handler which will receive a XML. I need to save the nodes into string parameters. 
This is the xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<alp> 
    <trade_no>11q</trade_no> 
    <out_trade_no>22z</out_trade_no>  
    <trade_status>T</trade_status>
</alp>
```

I have tried this -

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {            
        var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string strXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(strXml));
        ..........
}
```

or using DOM? please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LINQ XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

```
var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
var tradeNo = doc.Descendants("trade_no").FirstOrDefault().Value;
var outTradeNo = doc.Descendants("out_trade_no").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
   var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Here response contains the whole xml received. You can load it in DOM and fetch innerXml of nodes to get string for nodes.

But if you want to process the Xml nodes of the stream, I would suggest going for XPathReader instead of DOM approach

If you can detail how you want to use the resultant xml OR why you want it as string, I can suggest better.

**EDIT**

```
> I exactly need the node value, ie value of <trade_no>
```

To get value of trade_no you can either use DOM or XPathReader. Following is example with DOM

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(response);
    var tradeNoNode = document.SelectSingleNode("//trade_no");

    if(tradeNoNode != null) {
        var tradeNo = tradeNoNode.InnerText;
    }
}
```

For an efficient solution, please use [XPathReader](http://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=22677)

Comment: I exactly need the node value, ie value of `<trade_no>`